# How to get the result of a grep command on a variable into another variable

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am listing through files within a directory that match a given criteria. One of the things I wish to do with each file in the directory is extract its 6 figure date and place that in a variable. My script currently looks like this:

```
for i in $(ls $INPUT_DIR | egrep -i '^'$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX'[0-9][0-9]([0][1-9]|1[0-2])([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])'$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX); do   
 MYDATE=$("$i" | grep -oP '\d{6,6}')
 echo $MYDATE
done
```

The above leads to the error `"somefile": command not found`.

What seems strange to me is that if I replace `MYDATE=$("$i" | grep -oP '\d{6,6}')` with `echo "$i" | grep -oP '\d{6,6}'` all works fine.

How do I get my script to pass `"$i"` as a string rather than a command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to parse out a six digit number in file names that start with `$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX` and ends with `$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX`.

This will do that:

```
for name in "$INPUT_DIR/$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX"??????"$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX"; do
    test -f "$name" || continue

    number=${name#$INPUT_DIR/$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}
    number=${number%$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX}

    printf "Number = %s\n" "$number"
done
```

Change every `?` to `[0-9]` if you want to be sure to only match digits (`?` matches a single character regardless of what that character is).

The parameter substitutions in the loop removes the first part of the value of `$name` and then the last part of the remaining string, leaving the number (six characters between prefix and suffix) in the middle as the only thing left in the variable `$number`.

---

The command

```
MYDATE=$("$i" | grep -oP '\d{6,6}')
```

will, as you discovered, be interpreted as invoking whatever is in `$i` as a command.  At the same time you said that putting `echo` in front of `"$i"` would make it work, which it does:

```
MYDATE=$(echo "$i" | grep -oP '\d{6,6}')
```

Related to your code: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I have chosen this as the answer, as it is does address directly my particular query, though I appreciate others for pointing out other methods of looping through the files in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a slightly different way of looping through the filenames -- using bash's [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) to gather the filenames:

```
shopt -s extglob
for d in "${INPUT_DIR}"/"${INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}"[0-9][0-9]@(0[1-9]|1[0-9])@(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"${INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX}"
do 
  [[ $d =~ ${INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}([[:digit:]]+)${INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX} ]]
  MYDATE=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
```

The globbing syntax is nearly the same as the grep statement you had. Each set of `@(...)` introduces a request to match any of the given patterns, which are separated by `|`.  I noticed that the (presumed day) pattern of `[3]` was a single-character class, so I removed its surrounding brackets.

Once we have the filenames in the `for` loop, you can use bash's conditional expression's regular expression `=~` operator to strip out the digits into MYDATE.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(ls $INPUT_DIR | egrep -i '^'$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX'[0-9][0-9]([0][1-9]|1[0-2])([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])'$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX);
```

In general, there's no reason to use `ls` in a structure like this, it just makes the command more awkward to read, plus you run into issues with some corner cases (see [ParsingLs in BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). However, the regex you have can not be represented as a standard shell glob, so there's some point into using it. Though since this was tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), we can do it in the shell, either with [`extglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) (or using regex matches with the `[[ .. ]]` construct after a wider glob).

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in "$INPUT_DIR/$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX"[0-9][0-9]@(0[1-9]|1[0-2])@(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX" ; do
```

If you don't really need such a strict pattern, you could just use `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` instead.

In the assignment to `MYDATE`, I assume you just want to remove the prefix and the suffix. (though if your prefix/suffix contains a six-digit string, the grep would match that, too.)

```
MYDATE=${i#"$INPUT_DIR/"}              # remove the directory
MYDATE=${MYDATE#"$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX"}  # remove the prefix
MYDATE=${MYDATE%"$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX"}  # and the suffix
```

In full:

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in "$INPUT_DIR/$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX"[0-9][0-9]@(0[1-9]|1[0-2])@(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX" ; do
    MYDATE=${i#"$INPUT_DIR/"}              # remove the directory
    MYDATE=${MYDATE#"$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX"}  # remove the prefix
    MYDATE=${MYDATE%"$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX"}  # and the suffix
    echo "$MYDATE"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is passing "$i" as a string, but you are telling the shell to use it as a command. The line that says

```
MYDATE=$("$i" | grep -oP '\d{6,6}')
```

is telling the shell: "Expand the variable `i`, then run the resulting command $i, feeding its output through this `grep` command, and assign the result to the MYDATE variable". The `$(...)` does the same thing as the double backtick construct you use with the `echo "$i" | grep -oP '\d{6,6}'` command that makes it work. You simply need the `echo` command in either one of those to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [bash process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)? It looks like it would make your command way easier and without the need for loops or variables.

Basically process substitution is not well known but can be extremely powerful.

> Process substitution feeds the output of a process (or processes) into the stdin of another process.

so, your command could be reduced to something like this:

```
grep -oP '\d{6,6}'<(egrep -i '^'$INPUT_FILE_PREFIX'[0-9][0-9]([0][1-9]|1[0-2])([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01])'$INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX <(ls $INPUT_DIR))
```

The logic behind it is better understood with a simpler version:

```
user@yrmv-191108:~/nums$ ls .
1  10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
user@yrmv-191108:~/nums$ grep 1 <(ls .)
1
10
```

Comment: Thanks Jordi - I am actually running a number of processes in my loop, however for sake brevity I have just shown the one in my question above, so I think a loop is more practical for my purposes.